# WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/.. after updating today

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, software-center

I got a warning after running `$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Dist: Ubuntu 14.04.5

```
Preparing to unpack .../software-center_13.10-0ubuntu4.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking software-center (13.10-0ubuntu4.2) over (13.10-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libedit2:amd64 (3.1-20140620-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libavutil52:amd64 (6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up libavcodec54:amd64 (6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up libavformat54:amd64 (6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up libbsd0:amd64 (0.7.0-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libwebp5:amd64 (0.4.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libgd3:amd64 (2.2.3-3+deb.sury.org~trusty+0) ...
Setting up libjbig0:amd64 (2.1-3.1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libswscale2:amd64 (6:9.20-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up libwebpmux1:amd64 (0.4.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libyajl2:amd64 (2.1.0-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libgs9-common (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.6) ...
Setting up libgs9 (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.6) ...
Setting up ghostscript (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.6) ...
Setting up ghostscript-x (9.10~dfsg-0ubuntu10.6) ...
Setting up openssl (1.0.2j-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up software-center (13.10-0ubuntu4.2) ...
Updating software catalog...this may take a moment.
INFO:softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache:aptcache.open()
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/scribus:scribus.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mythtv-frontend:mythtv.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/furiusisomount:furiusisomount.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/jeex:jeex.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/rubrica:rubrica2.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/camorama:camorama.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/hasciicam:hasciicam.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/loook:loook.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mudlet:mudlet.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/openshot:openshot.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/omegat:omegat.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/wakeup:wakeup.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/acetoneiso:AcetoneISO.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/me-tv:me-tv.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/hdhomerun-config-gui:hdhr.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/chromium-browser:chromium-browser.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/workrave:workrave.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/timidity-interfaces-extra:timidity-interfaces-extra.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/mythtv-backend:mythtv-setup.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/remmina:remmina.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/acoustid-fingerprinter:acoustid-fingerprinter.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
WARNING:softwarecenter.db.update:The file: '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gnome-media-player:gnome-media-player.desktop' could not be read correctly. The application associated with this file will not be included in the software catalog. Please consider raising a bug report for this issue with the maintainer of that application
Software catalog update was successful.
```